# My AppleTV is in standby and still connects to Apple servers. Why and how to switch off?

Tags: network, sleep-wake, appletv, privacy

I use OpenWrt as router software and see this while AppleTV is in standby since weeks:

[image]

DuckDuckGo finds

- 17.57.144.53 is an IP address operated by Apple
- **Port 5223 Details**: Port used by Apple to maintain a persistent connection to APNs and receive push notifications. Some Apple applications that use this port: MobileMe, FaceTime, Game Center, APNs.

Just saying 1.2 MB is a lot traffic.

Why this behavior and how to switch off?

Answer (score 1):

Why? It's checking for the above-mentioned data.

Standby does not mean 'off' on any device these days. Your smart TV & cable TV box will be doing just the same sort of thing - Updating TV schedules, checking for messages from various services, checking for OS updates, etc etc.

Note: the entirety of 17.x.x.x belongs to Apple. You can really just allow the entire subnet.

Answer (score 1):

I think there might be a turn off option in the settings app, depending on which os you are running. If that doesn’t work, try cutting the power. I know it sounds silly, but that’s what i do when i can’t find the option